# How to JPA mapping a HashMap?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

How do I have do annotate a `HashMap<Enum, Boolean>` so that JPA can persist it?

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private Map<UserType, Boolean> settings;
}

public enum UserType {
    USER, ADMIN
}
```

I tried `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` but that gives me an error that `Boolean` is not an entity (which is true of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@`ManyToMany` is not optimum solution for `HashMap`. Use @ElementCollection annotaion to map your table, than an intermediate table will generate named `user_type` (as defined in annotaion). Here is the sample of annotation:

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_type")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "user_type_col")
    @Column(name = "boolean_col")
    private Map<UserType, Boolean> userType = new HashMap<>();
```